# I get this "Error while running convert: sh: convert: command not found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, captcha

I'm trying to use the gem called `Simple Captcha`

This requires ImageMagick installed on the machine.
I've installed it and `convert --version` shows this

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.2-10 2013-02-12 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib freetype jng jpeg lcms png ps tiff x xml zlib
```

However, it won't show the generated image when SimpleCaptcha is working.
So I took a look at the log. and it says this

```
  StandardError (Error while running convert: sh: convert: command not found):
  galetahub-simple_captcha (0.1.3) lib/simple_captcha/utils.rb:17:in `run'
  galetahub-simple_captcha (0.1.3) lib/simple_captcha/image.rb:76:in `generate_simple_captcha_image'
  galetahub-simple_captcha (0.1.3) lib/simple_captcha/middleware.rb:36:in `make_image'
  galetahub-simple_captcha (0.1.3) lib/simple_captcha/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  ...
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: do you do this?
cd /yourapp
convert --version
rails server

And THAT server instance barfs as you've described?

Comment: @RadBrad Thanks for the reply. What do you mean? sorry I don't get it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems `imagemagick` is missed. Try to install it:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and enter your password and then

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick php5-imagick
```

and then press *Return* to confirm the installation.

Comment: On Ubuntu-server-16, `sudo apt-get install -y imagemagick php5-imagick ` give me  `Package php5-imagick is not available, but is referred to by another package.`, then I  just run `sudo apt-get install -y imagemagick`  and restart server, everything works fine.

Comment: Mac: `brew install imagemagick`